# JavaFX How to get BorderPane height during runtime?

Tags: javafx

In my program I create different BorderPanes. How can I get their (diffrent) heights during runtime? When I use `borderPane.getHeight()` or `borderPane.getPrefHeight()` it always return -1.0 or 0.0.
Thanks!
Code example:

```
public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn1 = new Button("1");
    Button btn2 = new Button("2");
    Button btn3 = new Button("3");     
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    StackPane root = new StackPane();   
    borderPane.setCenter(btn1);
    borderPane.setBottom(btn2);
    borderPane.setTop(btn3);
    System.out.println("borderPane's height: "  + borderPane.getHeight()); //Print 0.0
    root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);       
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some code? I would expect `getPrefHeight()` to return `-1` as that is the default value, but `getHeight()` should return the current height.

Comment: If you try to get the height of the border pane before it's displayed, it will be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`borderPane.getHeight()` will print 0 since it is still not displayed when u are getting the height.

There are a couple of alternatives. The easiest is to surround your code with `PlarForm.runLater()`

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("borderPane's height: " + borderPane.getHeight());
            }
        });
```